# Joint density $f(x,y) = 30(1-x)y^2$, calculate marginal on $x^2 > y^2$ with $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: probability

Joint density $f(x,y) = 30(1-x)y^2$, calculate the marginals on $x^2 > y^2$ with $x \in (0,1)$

This is my setup for the two integral:

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-x}^{+x}30(1-x)y^2 dy $$ 
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_0^1 30(1-x)y^2 dx $$

The first one is the right result, but the $f_Y(y)$ is wrong. Any tips?

Comment: Marginal of $X$ looks okay, but I think $x$ should run from $|y|$ to $1$ in the formula of $f_Y$.

Comment: Why is that? I drew a picture but isn't the x going for just (0,1)?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $x^2>y^2\implies |x|>|y|\implies x>|y|$.

Comment: Yeah I need more coffe, that was dumb. Thanks!